# Meteor 1.1 - Callback when specific element renders on the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, meteor

I have some DOM elements that I don't directly have access to, as they are rendered from an API call. What I would like to do is add a class to this element once it's rendered on the DOM.

Using `Template.rendered` does not work, as the template renders properly before these DOM elements appear from the API.

My current solution is a `Meteor.setTimeout`—which might be the definition of a hack—and it only works about 90% of the time.

What is the best way to trigger a function when a particular DOM element is rendered?

Here is some of the relevant code from the API call:

```
Template.map.rendered = function() {

  return this.autorun(function() {
    var drawControl, drawnItems, mmap;
    if (Mapbox.loaded()) {
      L.mapbox.accessToken = '<API KEY>';
      L.mapbox.config.FORCE_HTTPS = true;

      mmap = L.mapbox.map('map', '<TOKEN>');

      L.control.scale().addTo(mmap);

      var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(mmap);

      drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        draw: {
            polygon: false,
            polyline: false,
            rectangle: true,
            circle: false,
            marker: false
          }
      });

      mmap.addControl(drawControl);
      mmap.addControl(L.mapbox.geocoderControl('mapbox.places', {
              autocomplete: true
          }));

      function showPolygonAreaEdited(e) {
        e.layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
          showPolygonArea({ layer: layer });
        });
      }

      function showPolygonArea(e) {

        coords = {
            lat1: normalizeLon(e.layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates[0][1][0]),
            lon1: normalizeLat(e.layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates[0][1][1]),
            lat2: normalizeLon(e.layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates[0][3][0]),
            lon2: normalizeLat(e.layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates[0][3][1])
        }

        featureGroup.clearLayers();
        featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer);
        e.layer.openPopup();


      }

      mmap.on('draw:created', showPolygonArea);
      mmap.on('draw:edited', showPolygonAreaEdited);

    }

  });
};
```

I've removed a lot of extraneous code, so this might not compile properly... But it has all the relevant bits.

The selector I initially tried to use was this:

```
Template.map.rendered = function() {
  $('.leaflet-draw-section').attr('data-intro', 'Hello step one!')
  ...
  ...
```

But it didn't work, since the API elements hadn't rendered yet.

Comment: What's the specific API you're using ? Does it provide its own callbacks / events when inserting in the DOM is done ?

Comment: I'm using the Mapbox API to render a map :) I don't believe it has the callback functions I'm looking for, but I will check now! I need a callback for when the control panel loads, and one for when the map tiles load (or one master callback for when the entire thing is finished loading).

Comment: Funny I was just looking for an answer to a similar question. It turns out to be a hard problem in Meteor in general and one where IMO Meteor is going to have to expose some new functionality. The general case is a template that embeds other templates and you want to do something (in my case, scroll to the bottom) after the embedded templates have *all* inserted their content into the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution comes from the Mapbox API. There is a callback on "ready":

```
var layer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets');
layer.on('ready', function() {
  // the layer has been fully loaded now, and you can
  // call .getTileJSON and investigate its properties
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [map box api](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.0/), it appears that `L.mapbox.map` does the rendering:

```
<script>
// Provide your access token
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'id1' //
// Create a map in the div #map
L.mapbox.map('map', 'id2');
// add your class to #map right here!!
</script>
```

If that doesnt work, them maybe `L.mapbox.map` is doing something asynchronous. They don't give you a callback, so a `window.setTimout(func, 0)` may be necessary

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code looks like this

```
Template.templatename.onRendered(function(){
    //yourcode
});
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. The template renders properly, but the API call hasn't finished rendering its DOM elements, so the error `Error: There is no element with given selector.`

Comment: @samcorcos got it for that you will need a call back function when api call has finish loading